# FileData orphan in a form on Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access

This is my first question on stack overflow so hopefully i've done it right.

Microsoft Access (part of the MS Office Professional Plus 2016 suite)

I am getting the error as attached "Link to Folder.FileData"

When I go into the applicable form there is a field available called "FileData" but I don't know what it relates to. It's not in the linked table?

I think if I can remove the FileData field from the form my problem will be solved.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Update the field available is called FileData not File.Data

Comment: When does this error occur - what is happening? FileData is a feature of Attachment type field.

Comment: It happens when I click on a button that opens a form. The error message box comes up and if i press enter the messge box goes away and the form loads as expected.

Comment: That isn't really an error message. It's a parameter input prompt because Access cannot find field named FileData. As I said, FileData is a property of Attachment type field. I have no idea why it is showing up isolated like that. I don't know why it asking for link.